# React build got bigger in size after using lazy and suspense

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

my production build was 12mb but the application had 16% performance in the lighthouse amongst other problems, so in order to optimize the performance i used lazy and suspense as lighthouse suggested. after changing most of the imports the performance became 25% but the build size became 160mb.
I want to know why that happened, how to fix it ,and some suggestions to optimize the performance as fast as possible.

```
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"react": "^17.0.2",
```

the warning :

```
Compiled with warnings.

chunk 19 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./src/pages/Shop/Settings/style.module.sass
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/components/customizes/PlaceholderPages/style.css
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s)

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  1.13 MB     build/static/js/28.c8f8246c.chunk.js
  1.1 MB      build/static/js/30.06366f0e.chunk.js
  1.08 MB     build/static/js/31.61e3c31d.chunk.js
  1.08 MB     build/static/js/32.f80b283f.chunk.js
  1.05 MB     build/static/js/49.a25d5e66.chunk.js
  1023.05 KB  build/static/js/48.0ecd2596.chunk.js
  1014.52 KB  build/static/js/44.f42ebfde.chunk.js
  976.71 KB   build/static/js/50.fdaf9aa2.chunk.js
  962.56 KB   build/static/js/45.ffa32983.chunk.js
  937.81 KB   build/static/js/55.713cc0fa.chunk.js
  913.63 KB   build/static/js/59.44230b7e.chunk.js
  843.87 KB   build/static/js/52.0ba0144a.chunk.js
  843.84 KB   build/static/js/51.8c93b9cf.chunk.js
  743.75 KB   build/static/js/83.98829869.chunk.js
  666.31 KB   build/static/js/39.08400dd7.chunk.js
  645.43 KB   build/static/js/74.ef033762.chunk.js
  537.67 KB   build/static/js/128.d6546b49.chunk.js
  468.79 KB   build/static/js/27.d3c4776e.chunk.js
  455.42 KB   build/static/js/47.f2ecee6a.chunk.js
  448.72 KB   build/static/js/165.e2cf25bd.chunk.js
  420.15 KB   build/static/js/22.b522831f.chunk.js
  419.06 KB   build/static/js/97.d4e67f08.chunk.js
  411.11 KB   build/static/js/33.1a79aa40.chunk.js
  398.88 KB   build/static/js/34.4667a3fc.chunk.js
  380.86 KB   build/static/js/35.e4524607.chunk.js
  375.89 KB   build/static/js/29.daabb8f7.chunk.js
  361.06 KB   build/static/js/38.cd9d5e77.chunk.js
  359.45 KB   build/static/js/46.9d6aab7e.chunk.js
  338.17 KB   build/static/js/43.2aaa84bf.chunk.js
  264.68 KB   build/static/js/40.b4955b7f.chunk.js
  259.12 KB   build/static/js/41.0d484a09.chunk.js
  258.98 KB   build/static/js/42.43aaf5c4.chunk.js
  244.05 KB   build/static/js/84.614f6b9e.chunk.js
  241.78 KB   build/static/js/87.00a5fc1a.chunk.js
  241.4 KB    build/static/js/86.8bf648d8.chunk.js
  241.02 KB   build/static/js/54.de887287.chunk.js
  241.01 KB   build/static/js/70.416d0370.chunk.js
  240.79 KB   build/static/js/124.6a213b63.chunk.js
  239.37 KB   build/static/js/58.d14ba157.chunk.js
  235.99 KB   build/static/js/106.92a0f8af.chunk.js
  235.66 KB   build/static/js/117.42da5054.chunk.js
  235.65 KB   build/static/js/111.bc8d0f30.chunk.js
  235.53 KB   build/static/js/104.67b4eebe.chunk.js
  235.51 KB   build/static/js/92.0b57307f.chunk.js
  234.99 KB   build/static/js/96.f4449443.chunk.js
  234.89 KB   build/static/js/100.04b4161c.chunk.js
  233.91 KB   build/static/js/110.f3aeff3b.chunk.js
  233.86 KB   build/static/js/102.b9243807.chunk.js
  233.61 KB   build/static/js/101.f0dd7400.chunk.js
  233.51 KB   build/static/js/115.58a1ecb8.chunk.js
  230.33 KB   build/static/js/63.96ef7764.chunk.js
  230.28 KB   build/static/js/64.d8fc443e.chunk.js
  230.25 KB   build/static/js/62.bb9fe095.chunk.js
  221.32 KB   build/static/js/71.3778f5cd.chunk.js
  219.42 KB   build/static/js/77.62f6c0b4.chunk.js
  217.79 KB   build/static/js/148.fbd628de.chunk.js
  211.97 KB   build/static/js/146.1aeb72ca.chunk.js
  211.65 KB   build/static/js/147.75b0a9d0.chunk.js
  207.25 KB   build/static/js/174.fc3dbe96.chunk.js
  179.31 KB   build/static/js/225.7c14613f.chunk.js
  177.62 KB   build/static/js/37.9fd9fd12.chunk.js
  175.3 KB    build/static/js/8.67702b17.chunk.js
  136.12 KB   build/static/js/65.30077cac.chunk.js
  123.55 KB   build/static/js/36.f5d08d6b.chunk.js
  111.22 KB   build/static/js/160.2c9e2e95.chunk.js
  111.08 KB   build/static/js/152.888a8407.chunk.js
  82.95 KB    build/static/js/89.63e20956.chunk.js
  74.29 KB    build/static/js/53.22cc42a0.chunk.js
  68.29 KB    build/static/js/73.8e22d331.chunk.js
  67.92 KB    build/static/js/107.2bc21852.chunk.js
  67.69 KB    build/static/js/60.ff057651.chunk.js
  67.68 KB    build/static/js/93.d61032d5.chunk.js
  65.97 KB    build/static/js/main.ed85c4c8.chunk.js
  62.15 KB    build/static/js/61.a596ce4d.chunk.js
  59.4 KB     build/static/js/66.1ef00890.chunk.js
  58.1 KB     build/static/js/72.e8fa4dda.chunk.js
  57.69 KB    build/static/js/98.e28df86b.chunk.js
  55.88 KB    build/static/js/123.b155b1e7.chunk.js
  55.84 KB    build/static/js/68.c6074b1f.chunk.js
  55.81 KB    build/static/js/122.d3e9ee2a.chunk.js
  55.79 KB    build/static/js/69.f0d4b5d8.chunk.js
  55.26 KB    build/static/js/67.3848af9e.chunk.js
  52.28 KB    build/static/js/118.74ba0433.chunk.js
  50.32 KB    build/static/js/135.f6acfbb4.chunk.js
  49.57 KB    build/static/js/56.1a510b38.chunk.js
  47.92 KB    build/static/js/167.8dc88aba.chunk.js
  45.8 KB     build/static/js/85.0322c3d5.chunk.js
  45.32 KB    build/static/js/76.41e3a135.chunk.js
  42.71 KB    build/static/js/79.cfe1a1ae.chunk.js
  42.71 KB    build/static/js/80.7847f6a4.chunk.js
  42.28 KB    build/static/js/143.e40b875b.chunk.js
  41.89 KB    build/static/js/57.6cebbeee.chunk.js
  40.85 KB    build/static/js/78.f9a49d10.chunk.js
  40.13 KB    build/static/js/99.81eb8656.chunk.js
  39.83 KB    build/static/js/81.e0f54511.chunk.js
  39.67 KB    build/static/js/103.506097ab.chunk.js
  38.83 KB    build/static/js/75.af6983a8.chunk.js
  38.13 KB    build/static/js/82.13c2dc2e.chunk.js
  37.91 KB    build/static/js/88.46e8ef14.chunk.js
  37.25 KB    build/static/js/91.ef82eb03.chunk.js
  36.96 KB    build/static/js/131.74516c39.chunk.js
  36.96 KB    build/static/js/130.0ba787b9.chunk.js
  36.84 KB    build/static/js/153.abfc3c7f.chunk.js
  36.48 KB    build/static/js/108.ff1c41b1.chunk.js
  36.38 KB    build/static/js/136.3a55ea23.chunk.js
  36.35 KB    build/static/js/112.d04394dc.chunk.js
  36.2 KB     build/static/js/113.67ae9fee.chunk.js
  35.71 KB    build/static/js/142.dffc2c27.chunk.js
  35.56 KB    build/static/js/90.25258ffe.chunk.js
  34.62 KB    build/static/js/109.f6f52664.chunk.js
  34.52 KB    build/static/js/114.beea0987.chunk.js
  34.43 KB    build/static/js/95.6e83cc81.chunk.js
  34.39 KB    build/static/js/94.13dc4a74.chunk.js
  34.28 KB    build/static/js/119.5d6f3693.chunk.js
  34.1 KB     build/static/js/116.e7736a85.chunk.js
  33.8 KB     build/static/js/121.a64b0e46.chunk.js
  33.31 KB    build/static/js/144.f6c9e6a3.chunk.js
  33.25 KB    build/static/js/120.82c807a9.chunk.js
  33.15 KB    build/static/js/149.ede72a41.chunk.js
  33.15 KB    build/static/js/164.e7f54072.chunk.js
  33.03 KB    build/static/js/150.3a994c1d.chunk.js
  33 KB       build/static/js/151.6f2e3c74.chunk.js
  32.88 KB    build/static/js/158.5dc41445.chunk.js
  32.17 KB    build/static/js/127.e7ead96c.chunk.js
  31.97 KB    build/static/js/156.637c210e.chunk.js
  31.88 KB    build/static/js/145.3b5d6660.chunk.js
  31.74 KB    build/static/js/157.bdf7fd71.chunk.js
  31.41 KB    build/static/js/159.0c66e4a7.chunk.js
  31.4 KB     build/static/js/138.f4402d79.chunk.js
  30.94 KB    build/static/js/214.419075c0.chunk.js
  29.94 KB    build/static/js/166.bbcd4f5f.chunk.js
  29.66 KB    build/static/js/163.e5973b82.chunk.js
  29.61 KB    build/static/js/162.22219393.chunk.js
  29.47 KB    build/static/js/182.81536b40.chunk.js
  29.18 KB    build/static/js/181.54201c45.chunk.js
  29.13 KB    build/static/js/170.5cbf2d80.chunk.js
  28.97 KB    build/static/js/169.f8fbf7e4.chunk.js
  28.93 KB    build/static/js/179.8ac62c35.chunk.js
  28.87 KB    build/static/js/180.bef2fe2b.chunk.js
  28.48 KB    build/static/js/177.bb6e434b.chunk.js
  27.59 KB    build/static/js/184.b91c4ee8.chunk.js
  27.31 KB    build/static/js/173.3e47e24f.chunk.js
  26.74 KB    build/static/js/16.d9423124.chunk.js
  23.82 KB    build/static/js/4.6d0a6be3.chunk.js
  22.07 KB    build/static/js/208.35b97c9d.chunk.js
  22.06 KB    build/static/js/205.00e0463e.chunk.js
  22.05 KB    build/static/js/9.4d40f763.chunk.js
  22.03 KB    build/static/js/207.e4ed4dff.chunk.js
  19.19 KB    build/static/js/129.c1d72dd0.chunk.js
  18.9 KB     build/static/js/17.5e6b9df2.chunk.js
  16.69 KB    build/static/js/178.c4ccb954.chunk.js
  15.16 KB    build/static/css/28.957ae106.chunk.css
  14.75 KB    build/static/css/30.8a4f30d1.chunk.css
  14.52 KB    build/static/css/31.ed67796e.chunk.css
  13.79 KB    build/static/js/7.58d52c0e.chunk.js
  11.27 KB    build/static/css/32.3ff0983f.chunk.css
  11.21 KB    build/static/css/45.392ed7c8.chunk.css
  11.18 KB    build/static/js/185.ff8e0105.chunk.js
  10.09 KB    build/static/css/44.c51d61f0.chunk.css
  10.06 KB    build/static/js/105.ce3f85db.chunk.js
  8.99 KB     build/static/js/168.472bf4c5.chunk.js
  8.89 KB     build/static/css/55.5bec8fc2.chunk.css
  8.85 KB     build/static/css/50.0fabe49a.chunk.css
  7.37 KB     build/static/js/154.210a971b.chunk.js
  7.14 KB     build/static/js/24.9ce575e6.chunk.js
  7.04 KB     build/static/js/15.b89720b2.chunk.js
  6.9 KB      build/static/js/155.9c9fa41f.chunk.js
  6.51 KB     build/static/css/34.9cddb91e.chunk.css
  6.4 KB      build/static/js/175.13e4df01.chunk.js
  6.33 KB     build/static/js/20.f426b0ec.chunk.js
  6.24 KB     build/static/js/137.37eb43e8.chunk.js
  6.18 KB     build/static/js/161.01035ec9.chunk.js
  5.95 KB     build/static/js/5.93d35f4e.chunk.js
  5.75 KB     build/static/js/13.74ceec74.chunk.js
  5.74 KB     build/static/css/33.e81ca939.chunk.css
  5.6 KB      build/static/js/23.2152f60b.chunk.js
  5.46 KB     build/static/js/126.cb8d7362.chunk.js
  5.45 KB     build/static/js/3.ab98fe03.chunk.js
  5.38 KB     build/static/js/18.fb71f2bb.chunk.js
  5.37 KB     build/static/js/171.c39798f7.chunk.js
  5.3 KB      build/static/js/172.8f2cd304.chunk.js
  5.22 KB     build/static/js/1.655503e9.chunk.js
  5.16 KB     build/static/js/0.50056ae7.chunk.js
  5.15 KB     build/static/css/48.3915610b.chunk.css
  5.13 KB     build/static/js/runtime-main.e0e93288.js
  5.01 KB     build/static/css/29.cf836062.chunk.css
  4.95 KB     build/static/css/35.8ccbd0be.chunk.css
  4.91 KB     build/static/css/74.96a8ab28.chunk.css
  4.91 KB     build/static/js/125.822fb6e0.chunk.js
  4.84 KB     build/static/js/204.106a832f.chunk.js
  4.77 KB     build/static/css/49.df8cb9d9.chunk.css
  4.76 KB     build/static/js/209.954b82d1.chunk.js
  4.57 KB     build/static/css/51.bc0d67a7.chunk.css
  4.57 KB     build/static/css/52.bc0d67a7.chunk.css
  4.56 KB     build/static/js/6.8da64b1c.chunk.js
  4.51 KB     build/static/js/176.bb38d925.chunk.js
  4.39 KB     build/static/js/186.58315f14.chunk.js
  4.31 KB     build/static/js/183.75061839.chunk.js
  4.31 KB     build/static/js/199.fac2a238.chunk.js
  4.3 KB      build/static/js/11.1183ea44.chunk.js
  4.25 KB     build/static/js/196.f1319e59.chunk.js
  4.13 KB     build/static/js/132.90f883bf.chunk.js
  4.03 KB     build/static/css/38.5ee65023.chunk.css
  4.02 KB     build/static/css/156.2834dbe0.chunk.css
  4.02 KB     build/static/js/188.4880cc9b.chunk.js
  3.97 KB     build/static/css/148.b39f4034.chunk.css
  3.96 KB     build/static/js/134.78d077d0.chunk.js
  3.94 KB     build/static/css/159.9818f2e6.chunk.css
  3.85 KB     build/static/css/39.fa42d12f.chunk.css
  3.78 KB     build/static/js/189.47329961.chunk.js
  3.78 KB     build/static/js/141.d4be137e.chunk.js
  3.74 KB     build/static/js/193.45ebb92b.chunk.js
  3.69 KB     build/static/css/46.6479abe8.chunk.css
  3.67 KB     build/static/css/47.389e1813.chunk.css
  3.64 KB     build/static/js/201.5426dca5.chunk.js
  3.59 KB     build/static/css/19.391ec014.chunk.css
  3.51 KB     build/static/js/195.88d3c56e.chunk.js
  3.5 KB      build/static/js/133.1d83d3ee.chunk.js
  3.45 KB     build/static/js/202.cec91852.chunk.js
  3.42 KB     build/static/css/71.f1c89649.chunk.css
  3.38 KB     build/static/js/187.be55a8d2.chunk.js
  3.37 KB     build/static/js/139.da80535a.chunk.js
  3.37 KB     build/static/js/140.e940bdb6.chunk.js
  3.34 KB     build/static/js/194.30a7d6d4.chunk.js
  3.3 KB      build/static/css/178.59a98dfa.chunk.css
  3.19 KB     build/static/css/98.3a887baa.chunk.css
  3.18 KB     build/static/js/210.09f30d6b.chunk.js
  3.17 KB     build/static/css/37.e6633473.chunk.css
  3.16 KB     build/static/css/62.0837051e.chunk.css
  3.16 KB     build/static/css/63.0837051e.chunk.css
  3.16 KB     build/static/css/64.0837051e.chunk.css
  3.01 KB     build/static/js/197.7321a9bc.chunk.js
  2.99 KB     build/static/css/185.13990150.chunk.css
  2.98 KB     build/static/css/77.bdb34486.chunk.css
  2.96 KB     build/static/js/200.2396d006.chunk.js
  2.68 KB     build/static/js/192.ed18ee6c.chunk.js
  2.67 KB     build/static/css/158.a1d2431b.chunk.css
  2.64 KB     build/static/css/150.74792cac.chunk.css
  2.58 KB     build/static/js/2.0d0dbae5.chunk.js
  2.53 KB     build/static/css/107.e7ba7bd6.chunk.css
  2.53 KB     build/static/css/27.c95f5849.chunk.css
  2.5 KB      build/static/css/84.bfbc3a07.chunk.css
  2.48 KB     build/static/js/206.ffc538cd.chunk.js
  2.4 KB      build/static/js/191.5004b417.chunk.js
  2.35 KB     build/static/css/124.c20b1e75.chunk.css
  2.31 KB     build/static/js/19.846ffaf6.chunk.js
  2.27 KB     build/static/css/65.ddd4b3d2.chunk.css
  2.26 KB     build/static/js/190.3b277bc7.chunk.js
  2.23 KB     build/static/js/12.9827d6d9.chunk.js
  2.18 KB     build/static/css/89.c0c5344a.chunk.css
  2.14 KB     build/static/css/54.26709ccc.chunk.css
  2.11 KB     build/static/css/96.c7db7a0c.chunk.css
  2.03 KB     build/static/css/149.41c3c957.chunk.css
  2.02 KB     build/static/css/115.fa79db1e.chunk.css
  1.99 KB     build/static/css/102.3915895b.chunk.css
  1.95 KB     build/static/css/40.25eb1232.chunk.css
  1.94 KB     build/static/css/195.2684d2b0.chunk.css
  1.94 KB     build/static/css/72.a68901a1.chunk.css
  1.93 KB     build/static/css/59.e006c4e2.chunk.css
  1.93 KB     build/static/css/104.09b9e2dc.chunk.css
  1.92 KB     build/static/css/main.7d63c190.chunk.css
  1.92 KB     build/static/css/92.492ed981.chunk.css
  1.89 KB     build/static/js/198.3cb47081.chunk.js
  1.89 KB     build/static/css/101.9af18135.chunk.css
  1.88 KB     build/static/css/186.ab3969cc.chunk.css
  1.87 KB     build/static/css/103.c49245dc.chunk.css
  1.82 KB     build/static/css/110.adacd9d1.chunk.css
  1.8 KB      build/static/css/106.0fb044fa.chunk.css
  1.8 KB      build/static/css/41.cd41cfe4.chunk.css
  1.8 KB      build/static/css/58.cf8c09a7.chunk.css
  1.78 KB     build/static/js/203.9cab3565.chunk.js
  1.76 KB     build/static/css/83.257960f6.chunk.css
  1.74 KB     build/static/css/87.64d5c49f.chunk.css
  1.74 KB     build/static/css/111.3fb4017f.chunk.css
  1.74 KB     build/static/css/67.b73e2616.chunk.css
  1.74 KB     build/static/css/97.3fb4017f.chunk.css
  1.73 KB     build/static/css/42.732a1517.chunk.css
  1.72 KB     build/static/css/53.af662bef.chunk.css
  1.68 KB     build/static/css/86.dfcbaf28.chunk.css
  1.68 KB     build/static/css/202.cee201dc.chunk.css
  1.67 KB     build/static/css/117.8bd402e0.chunk.css
  1.66 KB     build/static/css/70.e2f40742.chunk.css
  1.63 KB     build/static/css/68.94d36a2d.chunk.css
  1.59 KB     build/static/css/188.bccd85e0.chunk.css
  1.57 KB     build/static/css/69.66b57c19.chunk.css
  1.56 KB     build/static/css/153.e71f3f7c.chunk.css
  1.54 KB     build/static/js/218.9e7091de.chunk.js
  1.51 KB     build/static/css/128.ed0d5003.chunk.css
  1.51 KB     build/static/css/147.13b29488.chunk.css
  1.49 KB     build/static/css/166.e15d945e.chunk.css
  1.49 KB     build/static/css/201.cb53fbe3.chunk.css
  1.49 KB     build/static/css/61.5c764524.chunk.css
  1.48 KB     build/static/css/146.c69782a0.chunk.css
  1.46 KB     build/static/css/60.0349afdb.chunk.css
  1.45 KB     build/static/css/143.e3de381f.chunk.css
  1.45 KB     build/static/css/169.69783b55.chunk.css
  1.45 KB     build/static/css/78.b85dbc29.chunk.css
  1.45 KB     build/static/css/66.b44322b4.chunk.css
  1.43 KB     build/static/css/43.03f61edd.chunk.css
  1.43 KB     build/static/css/213.ca467815.chunk.css
  1.4 KB      build/static/css/145.6bc29ed7.chunk.css
  1.4 KB      build/static/css/73.4414b5f4.chunk.css
  1.38 KB     build/static/css/182.9b0dd6e4.chunk.css
  1.36 KB     build/static/css/93.44913180.chunk.css
  1.36 KB     build/static/css/90.a8552c72.chunk.css
  1.35 KB     build/static/css/157.3b333ec0.chunk.css
  1.34 KB     build/static/css/100.46054e11.chunk.css
  1.32 KB     build/static/css/163.a50bc524.chunk.css
  1.29 KB     build/static/css/82.c6d7c032.chunk.css
  1.28 KB     build/static/css/154.60bffa33.chunk.css
  1.23 KB     build/static/css/151.45285d22.chunk.css
  1.23 KB     build/static/css/168.0ab2946a.chunk.css
  1.2 KB      build/static/css/138.91fda93d.chunk.css
  1.2 KB      build/static/css/164.aedd281d.chunk.css
  1.17 KB     build/static/css/85.c244012f.chunk.css
  1.16 KB     build/static/js/212.70692d73.chunk.js
  1.15 KB     build/static/css/99.403d920b.chunk.css
  1.13 KB     build/static/css/91.7a31f2b3.chunk.css
  1.13 KB     build/static/css/94.7a31f2b3.chunk.css
  1.13 KB     build/static/css/95.7a31f2b3.chunk.css
  1.1 KB      build/static/js/217.555f5645.chunk.js
  1.1 KB      build/static/css/135.83f33c24.chunk.css
  1.09 KB     build/static/css/122.b4e9a2c1.chunk.css
  1.09 KB     build/static/css/123.b4e9a2c1.chunk.css
  1.09 KB     build/static/css/152.d4e9156e.chunk.css
  1.08 KB     build/static/css/105.468f9bd1.chunk.css
  1.07 KB     build/static/js/211.1be0ba38.chunk.js
  1.05 KB     build/static/css/171.b45a3866.chunk.css
  1.05 KB     build/static/css/172.5347acab.chunk.css
  1.05 KB     build/static/js/219.098cd18c.chunk.js
  1.03 KB     build/static/css/196.4235b6c6.chunk.css
  1.02 KB     build/static/css/116.341b7d2b.chunk.css
  1.02 KB     build/static/css/136.b1261b4b.chunk.css
  1 KB        build/static/css/162.4b62fc77.chunk.css
  1008 B      build/static/css/184.e5dfcf4e.chunk.css
  993 B       build/static/css/114.3d6bc140.chunk.css
  991 B       build/static/css/120.001385d0.chunk.css
  990 B       build/static/css/130.90c5457d.chunk.css
  990 B       build/static/css/131.90c5457d.chunk.css
  963 B       build/static/css/176.41ddef84.chunk.css
  937 B       build/static/js/14.c1d7443a.chunk.js
  924 B       build/static/css/193.c93808ee.chunk.css
  911 B       build/static/css/142.fad7cf31.chunk.css
  908 B       build/static/css/211.8fa53bd5.chunk.css
  893 B       build/static/css/174.5befad3c.chunk.css
  888 B       build/static/css/200.2143db4c.chunk.css
  888 B       build/static/css/212.2143db4c.chunk.css
  880 B       build/static/css/108.152c3ace.chunk.css
  878 B       build/static/css/194.d4d1b975.chunk.css
  872 B       build/static/css/113.1eed62ed.chunk.css
  872 B       build/static/css/155.a58fad09.chunk.css
  866 B       build/static/css/109.83f3a130.chunk.css
  865 B       build/static/css/167.454ab64e.chunk.css
  865 B       build/static/css/170.454ab64e.chunk.css
  859 B       build/static/css/160.76e4530b.chunk.css
  858 B       build/static/css/192.2004bf52.chunk.css
  838 B       build/static/css/161.1aa68746.chunk.css
  838 B       build/static/css/165.8820dffc.chunk.css
  830 B       build/static/css/79.7a107fe8.chunk.css
  830 B       build/static/css/80.7a107fe8.chunk.css
  814 B       build/static/css/81.3389c31a.chunk.css
  785 B       build/static/css/144.b0773257.chunk.css
  769 B       build/static/css/119.9058e2cf.chunk.css
  769 B       build/static/css/121.9058e2cf.chunk.css
  753 B       build/static/css/177.64ad4acf.chunk.css
  747 B       build/static/css/175.1db66c37.chunk.css
  736 B       build/static/js/21.7345cc3a.chunk.js
  694 B       build/static/js/224.1acb5cb9.chunk.js
  692 B       build/static/js/213.75901f41.chunk.js
  690 B       build/static/css/112.a9640e19.chunk.css
  670 B       build/static/css/56.57c34d63.chunk.css
  670 B       build/static/css/57.57c34d63.chunk.css
  670 B       build/static/css/75.57c34d63.chunk.css
  668 B       build/static/css/76.57c34d63.chunk.css
  666 B       build/static/css/209.2e0bf759.chunk.css
  660 B       build/static/css/118.38513f55.chunk.css
  656 B       build/static/js/10.6768af2a.chunk.js
  624 B       build/static/css/216.2841aeab.chunk.css
  619 B       build/static/css/88.e4cf43a8.chunk.css
  593 B       build/static/css/215.5de31f7e.chunk.css
  584 B       build/static/css/183.f9815d23.chunk.css
  561 B       build/static/css/127.f7d3a776.chunk.css
  561 B       build/static/css/187.f7d3a776.chunk.css
  560 B       build/static/js/216.0bf749d2.chunk.js
  508 B       build/static/css/199.742bf942.chunk.css
  501 B       build/static/css/179.74db12db.chunk.css
  501 B       build/static/css/180.74db12db.chunk.css
  501 B       build/static/css/181.74db12db.chunk.css
  501 B       build/static/css/189.926784c0.chunk.css
  477 B       build/static/js/215.e2bcaa73.chunk.js
  456 B       build/static/css/18.773d9281.chunk.css
  456 B       build/static/css/204.773d9281.chunk.css
  415 B       build/static/css/198.3b63a8ec.chunk.css
  354 B       build/static/css/21.ab00c1d3.chunk.css
  345 B       build/static/css/197.f089bb1f.chunk.css
  290 B       build/static/css/125.e19badfc.chunk.css
  282 B       build/static/css/203.e1921915.chunk.css
  242 B       build/static/css/217.a670269a.chunk.css
  224 B       build/static/js/220.2bcdea43.chunk.js
  215 B       build/static/js/221.c73d6acf.chunk.js
  211 B       build/static/css/173.6a051d25.chunk.css
  200 B       build/static/css/190.f3becd00.chunk.css
  197 B       build/static/js/223.acea1a0e.chunk.js
  196 B       build/static/js/222.95e379a6.chunk.js
  153 B       build/static/css/191.3541a123.chunk.css
  98 B        build/static/css/210.d75e55bf.chunk.css

The bundle size is significantly larger than recommended.
Consider reducing it with code splitting: 
You can also analyze the project dependencies:
```